# How to cast Object[] to Row[]?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I read JSON data from file into `Dataset` as follows (Spark 2.2.2, Java):

```
Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().json(filePath).as(Encoders.bean(Row.class));
```

The  I want to collect rows into a driver.

```
Row[] rows = df.collect();
```

The function `collect()` returns `Object[]`. How can I cast to `Row[]`?

Comment: Why try to have an row !? Use Jackson to parse your Json and get an datastructure.

Comment: `// Jackson mapper
private final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

private Object toObject(String json, Class clazz) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
 return mapper.readValue(json, clazz);
}`

`Class` Is the entry point of the Object representation of the Json structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DataSet.collectAsList()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#collectAsList--) method to get a `List` which you can convert to typed array. This will however result in additional memory allocation for the list:

```
List<Row> list = df.collectAsList();
Row[] arr = list.toArray(new Row[0]);
```

Comment: I get the compilation error `Array initializer expected` at the last line.

Comment: @Mozimaki forgot to add array size, should be `new Row[0]`